# jQuery .load getlink div content for every url in a certain class

Tags: jquery, load

I seem to be stumped on bit of jQuery I'm writing.

This is approximately the code I have so far...

```
<div class='item_url' style='display:none';>
<a href = 'http://test.com/01'>http://test.com/01</a>
</div>
<div>Title 01</div>
<div class='status'></div>

<div class='item_url' style='display:none';>
<a href = 'http://test.com/02'>http://test.com/02</a>
</div>
<div>Title 02</div>
<div class='status'></div>

<div class='item_url' style='display:none';>
<a href = 'http://test.com/03'>http://test.com/03</a>
</div>
<div>Title 03</div>
<div class='status'></div>

    <script>
    $(function(){
        var getlink = $("div.item_url").text();
        $(".status").load(getlink + #item_status");
    });
    </script>
```

I'm trying to...

1. Grab the link from each div with the class "item_url"
2. Go to that link and get the content from the div with the id "item_status"
3. Load the content I received from step 2 and populate the div with the class "status"
4. And I'm trying to have this loop and cascade the populated data appropriately

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the `div`s, retrieve the link from the text, identify what `div.status` is next after each div and then load the data into this `div.status`.

```
$(function(){
    $("div.item_url").each(function(i,item) {
        // item refers to the next div.item_url found in the DOM
        var getlink = $(item).text();
        // get a reference to the div with class status that follows this div
        var nextStatusDiv = $(item).next(".status");
        $(nextStatusDiv).load(getlink + " #item_status", function() {
            console.log("Loaded item status " + i + " successfully"; // for debug purposes
        });
    }
});
```